# Automatic Countdown Timer on Button Click

Tags: android, countdowntimer, android-handler

So I'm creating a workout app in which I have to change the text on the button after a certain amount of time to represent the new set. Once the "Start" button is clicked I want the timer to run automatically until all the workout sets are done. If the "Pause" button is pressed, the current timer is stopped until the start button is pressed again. I was wondering how to go about this. I tried to do it in a for loop creating a new timer each time, but it stopped after one run through. Any ideas on this? I had though about using a Handler to do this, but I'm not sure how to.

```
package com.dwolford.workoutroutine;

import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class Vertical extends ActionBarActivity {

Handler handler = new Handler();
Button jumpRope;
Button start;
Button pause;
Button back;
EditText timeLeft;
String[] verticalWorkouts = {"JUMP ROPE", "STRETCH", "JUMP ROPE", "STRETCH",
        "SLOW MOTION SQUATS", "STRETCH", "LATERAL JUMPS", "STRETCH", "ALTERNATING JUMP LUNGES", "STRETCH", "TUCK JUMPS", "STRETCH", "TOE RAISES", "STRETCH",
        "SLOW MOTION SQUATS", "STRETCH", "LATERAL JUMPS", "STRETCH", "ALTERNATING JUMP LUNGES", "STRETCH", "TUCK JUMPS", "STRETCH", "TOE RAISES", "STRETCH",
        "SLOW MOTION SQUATS", "STRETCH", "LATERAL JUMPS", "STRETCH", "ALTERNATING JUMP LUNGES", "STRETCH", "TUCK JUMPS", "STRETCH", "TOE RAISES", "STRETCH"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vertical);


    jumpRope = (Button)findViewById(R.id.jumpRope);
    jumpRope.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    jumpRope.requestFocus();


    timeLeft = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.time_left);
    start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            for(int i = 0; i < verticalWorkouts.length; i++)
            {
                final int iTemp = i;
                new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        timeLeft.setText("secs: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                    }

                    int temp = iTemp;
                    public void onFinish() {
                        timeLeft.setText("done!");

                        jumpRope.setText(verticalWorkouts[temp]);
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        }
    });

    pause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pause);
    pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            jumpRope.setText(verticalWorkouts[2]);
        }
    });

    back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_vertical, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Here is the XML:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="WORKOUT: VERTICAL"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:height="50dp"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Toe Raises"

    android:state_pressed="true"

    android:id="@+id/toeRaises"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tuckJumps"
    android:background="@drawable/button_gradient"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Tuck Jumps"
    android:id="@+id/tuckJumps"
    android:layout_below="@+id/altJumpLunge"
    android:background="@drawable/button_gradient"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Alternating jump lunges"
    android:id="@+id/altJumpLunge"
    android:layout_below="@+id/latJump"
    android:background="@drawable/button_gradient"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Lateral jumps"
    android:id="@+id/latJump"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button7"
    android:background="@drawable/button_gradient"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Slow motion squats"
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/stretch"
    android:background="@drawable/button_gradient"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Stretch"
    android:id="@+id/stretch"
    android:layout_below="@+id/jumpRope"
    android:background="@drawable/button_gradient"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="JUMP ROPE"
    android:id="@+id/jumpRope"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/button_gradient"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TIME:"
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:height="50dp"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/jumpRope"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/title"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/title" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sets Left: "
    android:id="@+id/setsLeft"
    android:height="50dp"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toeRaises"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Pause"
    android:id="@+id/pause"
    android:background="@drawable/button_gradient"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="start"
    android:id="@+id/start"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pause"
    android:background="@drawable/button_gradient"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="back"
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:background="@drawable/button_gradient"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toeRaises"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/toeRaises"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/latJump"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/latJump" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/time_left"
    android:layout_below="@+id/time"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/back"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/back"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/time"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/time" />
```

Comment: If you question is answered, make sure you mark the reply as answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my application i implemented a handler. Here is an untested excerpt:

```
private TextView time;
private boolean isPause;
private long startTime;
private long millis;
private long elapsedTime;
private final int MAXTIME = 10000;
private Handler timeHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable timeRunnable = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public synchronized void run(){
        if(!isPause){
            millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            updateMyTextView();
            checkEnd();
        }
        //here you can add other stuff...
        timeHandler.postDelayed(this, 500); 
}};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //...

    isPause = false;
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerTextView);
    time.setText("Time: " + String.valueOf(MAXTIME/1000)); //MAXTIME -> how many milliseconds your timer should work overall
    elapsedTime = 0; //buffer for pause

    timeHandler.postDelayed(timeRunnable, 0);        
}

private void updateMyTextView(){
    timerTextView.setText("Time: " + String.valueOf((MAXTIME-millis)/1000));
}

private synchronized void checkEnd(){
    if(millis >= MAXTIME){
        isPause = true;
        timerTextView.setText("Time: OUT OF TIME");
    }
}

private void startAgain(){
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    time.setText("Time: " + String.valueOf(MAXTIME/1000));
    elapsedTime = 0;
    isPause = false;
}

@Override
public synchronized void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == pause){
        if (isPause) {
            isPause = false;
            SoundManager.getInstance().resume();
            pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - elapsedTime ;
        } else {
            isPause = true;
            SoundManager.getInstance().pause();
            pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.start);
            elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        }
    }
    //... here you can add buttons for restart
}

@Override
public synchronized void onPause() {
    elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;           
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public synchronized void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - elapsedTime ;
}
```

In a Runnable i am updating a time variable which is called millis. There is one button for start/pausing the countdown. If the button ist pressed, the variable elapsedTime helps to restore the correct time after pause. If you want to restart you can call the method startAgain(). The runtime is specified with the constant MAXTIME.

Answer (score 0):

One other way I can think of is keep the timer running on a separate thread.

Declare `long lastPauseTime` , `long currentTime`, `long elapsedTime`  and `boolean isPaused` as field variables. Toggle `isPaused` whenever pause button is pressed. And implement this pseudo code in a thread:

```
while countdownTime > 0: 

    if isPaused:
        lastPauseTime = currentTime
    else: 
        elapsedTime = elapsedTime + (currentTime - lastPauseTime)

    countdownTime = timeLimit - elapsedTime 
    TextView --> display countdownTime
```

Then enhance these with start, stop, exercise type etc features.